# Minimum wage vs. minimum salary and “three minimum salaries”

Tags: word-usage, cultural-correctness

Here in Brazil people don’t usually talk about *wages* (how much you make per hour), but about *salaries* (how much one makes in a month).

Does it make sense to talk about minimum salary, or even in this case is it better to talk about minimum wages?

Also, down here we have the notion of “how many minimum salaries” workers earn. Say if the minimum salary is R$1000, then if one makes R$3000 can you say that person makes “three minimum salaries”?

Does this notion make any sense in English?

So could you say that that person makes “three minimum wages” in this case?

Comment: You can talk about "minimum salary", but it's not a set phrase like "minimum wage." Nobody in America says "I earn the minimum salary." You cannot say "I earn three minimum wages", but you can say "I earn three *times* the minimum wage."

Comment: Related: [Wages and Salaries](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161726/wages-and-salaries) (closed as Off Topic for much the same reason I closevoted this one).

Comment: Also, salaries do not well reflect the wages of part time employees. If I make $100 per hour, but only work 10 hours per month, my monthly salary is only $1000. Sounds low, but I am very well paid *per hour*.

Comment: @Silenus You cannot say, "I earn three minimum wages" unless you have three minimum-wage jobs, and you use "I earn three minimum wages" to communicate that fact.

Answer (score 1):

Just do some reading about wages and salaries in English, and you'll find the common phrases.  For example, you can read about the frustrated recent college graduates who find themselves working at minimum-wage jobs.  You will notice that in the U.S. at least, people don't think in terms of multiples of the minimum wage.  You'll also see people talking about making six figures -- this means the person makes at least $100,000 per year.